# CorDapp Example Build Fail

Tags: java, kotlin, corda

[1. I am trying to run CorDapp example through Terminal using guidance as follows- "https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#downloading-the-example-cordapp".

2. Now, upon running "gradlew.bat deployNodes" command, build is failing.
3. As per the link in Pt# 1, it is expected to get the nodes created in under "workflow-kotlin/build/nodes", but actually batch execution is picking up "workflow-java/build/nodes" directory.
4. java version "1.8.0_221"; Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11);
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
5. C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example>gradlew.bat deployNodes

> Task :workflows-java:deployNodes
>   Running Cordform task

Deleting C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes
Bootstrapping local test network in C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes
Generating node directory for Notary
Generating node directory for PartyA
Generating node directory for PartyB
Generating node directory for PartyC
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...

... still waiting. If this is taking longer than usual, check the node logs.

Error while generating node info file C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs

2019-09-15 01:59:17,900 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2019-09-15 01:59:17,900 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream

Logs can be found in: C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs

> Task :workflows-java:deployNodes FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':workflows-java:deployNodes'.

  > Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.
  >   Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs.

  6. Errors from PartyA Log as below:-
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:04,484Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): minValue is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:04,781Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-11::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-11::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:04,796Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-12::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-12::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:04,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-13::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-13::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,281Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-1::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-1::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,281Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-2::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-2::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,281Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-3::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-3::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,281Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-4::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-4::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,281Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-5::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-5::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,421Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-6::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-6::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,468Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-7::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-7::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,499Z [main] liquibase.info - Successfully acquired change log lock
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,593Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): minValue is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,749Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-11::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-11::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,781Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-12::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-12::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,781Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-13::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/vault-schema.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-13::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-1::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-1::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-2::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-2::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-3::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-3::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-4::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-4::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-5::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-5::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-6::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-6::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     [INFO ] 2019-09-15T07:31:05,812Z [main] liquibase.info - master.changelog.json: migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-7::R3.Corda: Skipping changeSet migration/node-core.changelog-pkey.xml::non-clustered_pk-7::R3.Corda due to validation error(s): clustered is not allowed on h2
     ]1

Comment: I don't know much about Corda, but it actually gives you a lot of info about what went wrong (e.g. logs, which you should definitely attach to your question) and also various stuff that you could try ("Run with --stacktrace option" etc.) to get even more info on what went wrong.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. Now, I ran "gradlew.bat --stacktrace deployNodes
" command, build is failing.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I ran "gradlew.bat --stacktrace deployNodes
" command in intelliJ Terminal. Now, it is resulting in successful bootstrapping of "workflows-java:deployNodes", but "workflows-kotlin:deployNodes" is failing while creating "node info" files. It is also giving Warning- "Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream".

Comment: Well, as the error messages say, those parameters just „get more log output“. You have to Link a pastebin of those logs in your question so we can have a look. Also please accept the edit, your question is pretty unreadable as is.

Comment: Can you also paste in your question, the error messages from the  "C:\Users\axsx1_000\samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs"?

Comment: Hi, Log file is too big to be copy pasted in comments. In this portal, Is there a way to attach the log file with Question or Comment?

Comment: Can you just search the log file for `[ERROR]` lines and post those?

Answer (score 0):

Which corda version are you using?
if you are using corda 4, you can try corda 3 and check if same issue happens.
hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
gradlew.bat clean deployNodes
```

Here **clean** clear previous transaction data and persistent.mv.db file gets recreated.